# Using tm and rpart in R: decision tree for textual data?

Tags: r, tm, rpart

I am using the `tm` package in R to create a corpus of text documents and I would like to create a decision tree with `rpart` for classification purposes. However, I can't find any examples on the internet about using textual data with `rpart`. Is it even possible or are there other packages I could use?

Comment: Where did you look? There should be [several examples](https://www.google.com/search?q="DocumentTermMatrix"+"rpart")

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starter:

```
library(tm)
library(rpart)
docs <- c(txt1="Hello world", txt2="lorem ipsum")
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(docs)), control = list(weight = weightBin))
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
train <- as.data.frame(m)
train$Docs <- factor(rownames(m), labels=names(docs))
fit <- rpart(Docs~.,data=train, control = rpart.control(minsplit=1))
test <- data.frame(hello=c(1,0),world=c(0,0),ipsum=c(0,1),lorem=c(0,0), row.names=letters[1:2])
predict(fit, newdata=test, type="class")
#    a    b 
# txt1 txt2 
# Levels: txt1 txt2
```

Comment: What do you have to put in `train$Docs <- factor(rownames(m), labels=names(docs))` (specifically the labels part) if you have a big corpus and a separate 'class' variable which says which class the document belongs to (i.e. class a, b, c for example). I tried `labels=class` but it says `duplicated levels in factors are deprecated`